# Spring REST API multiple RequestParams vs controller implementation

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, spring-boot

I'm wondering about proper way of implementating of controller in case of GET request with multiple request params given. In my understanding of REST it's much better to have one endpoint with additional parameters for filtering/sorting than several endpoints (one for each case). I'm just wondering about maintanance and extensibility of such endpoint. Please have a look on example below :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customers")
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepo;

    @GetMapping
    public Page<Customer> findCustomersByFirstName(
                @RequestParam("firstName") String firstName,
                @RequestParam("lastName") String lastName,
                @RequestParam("status") Status status, Pageable pageable) {

        if (firstName != null) {
            if (lastName != null) {
                if (status != null) {
                    return customerRepo.findByFirstNameAndLastNameAndStatus(
                                                    firstName, lastName, status, pageable);
                } else {
                    return customerRepo.findByFirstNameAndLastName(
                                                    firstName, lastName, pageable);
                }
            } else {
                // other combinations omitted for sanity
            }
        } else {
            // other combinations omitted for sanity
        }
    }
}
```

Such endpoint seems to be very convenient to use (order of parameters doesn't matter, all of them are optional...), but maintaining something like this looks like a hell (number of combinations can be enormous).

My question is - what is the best way to deal with something like this? How is it designed in "professional" APIs?

Comment: Good question, but from my point of view its a litte too broad. _How to designe in a professional_ way could have many answers with many different solutions. It would be good to ask a more specific question to get a good answer for a particular case. To give an example: You could send one parameter as JSON which represents your Customer POJO and use queryDSL to generate predicates for building dynamic queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the best way to deal with something like this?

The best way to deal with it is to use the tools already available. As you are using Spring Boot and, I assume therefore, Spring Data JPA then enable the QueryDsl suppport and web support extensions for Spring Data JPA.

You controller then simply becomes:

```
@GetMapping
public Page<Customer> searchCustomers( 
        @QuerydslPredicate(root = Customer.class) Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable) {
   return customerRepo.findBy(predicate, pageable);
}
```

and your repository is simply extended to support QueryDsl:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Customer, Long>, 
            QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Customer>{

}
```

**You can now query by any combination of params without writing any further code.**

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.type-safe
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.extensions.querydsl

Comment: That's exactly I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Good day. I can't call myself a professional, but here are some tips which can make this controller looks better.

- Use DTO instead of using a group of parameters

```
public class CustomerDTO {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String status;

}
```

With this class your method's signature will look like this:

```
@GetMapping
public Page<Customer> findCustomersByFirstName(CustomerDTO customerDTO, Pageable pageable) {
    ...
}
```

- Use validation if you need one

For example, you can make some of these fields are required:

```
public class CustomerDTO {

    @NotNull(message = "First name is required")
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String status;

}
```

Don't forget to add @Valid annotation before the DTO parameter in your controller.

- Use specification instead of this block with if-else

Here is a great guide on how to do it - [REST Query Language with Spring Data JPA Specifications](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-specifications)

- Use the service layer, don't need to call repository from the controller

```
@GetMapping
public Page<Customer> findCustomersByFirstName(@Valid CustomerDTO customerDTO, BindingResult bindingResult, Pageable pageable) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        // error handling
    }
    return customerService.findAllBySpecification(new CustomerSpecification(customerDTO));
}
```

Your controller should not contain any logic about working with entities or some business stuff. It's only about handling request/errors, redirects, views, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Its good to have a **POST** request with such validations instead of a **GET** request.You can use following method for the controller.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/findCustomer",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> findCustomersByFirstName(@Valid @RequestBody Customer customer){
   return customerRepo.findByFirstNameAndLastNameAndStatus(customer.getFirstName, customer.getLastName(), customer.getStatus(), pageable);
```

}

use the DTO as follows.

```
public class Customer {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String status;

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName= firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName= lastName;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status= status;
}

public LivenessInputModel(String firstName, String lastName, String status) {
    this.firstName= firstName;
    this.lastName= lastName;
    this.status= status;
}

public LivenessInputModel() {

}
```

}

And add a controller level exception advice to return the response in errors.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerExceptionAdvice {

private static final String EXCEPTION_TRACE = "Exception Trace:";

private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ControllerExceptionAdvice.class);

public ControllerExceptionAdvice() {
    super();
}

@ExceptionHandler({ BaseException.class })
public ResponseEntity<String> handleResourceException(BaseException e, HttpServletRequest request,
                                                      HttpServletResponse response) {

    log.error(EXCEPTION_TRACE, e);

    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

    responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    BaseExceptionResponse exceptionDto = new BaseExceptionResponse(e);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionDto.toString(), responseHeaders, e.getHttpStatus());
}


@ExceptionHandler({ Exception.class })
public ResponseEntity<String> handleException(Exception e, HttpServletRequest request,
                                              HttpServletResponse response) {

    log.error(EXCEPTION_TRACE, e);

    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

    responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

    BaseExceptionResponse exceptionDto = new BaseExceptionResponse(httpStatus.value(),
            ExceptionMessages.INTERNAL_DEFAULT);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionDto.toString(), responseHeaders, httpStatus);
}


@ExceptionHandler({ MethodArgumentNotValidException.class })
public ResponseEntity<String> handleValidationException(MethodArgumentNotValidException e,
                                                        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    log.error(EXCEPTION_TRACE, e);

    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

    responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    ValidationException validationEx = new ValidationException(e);
    BaseExceptionResponse exceptionDto = new BaseExceptionResponse(validationEx);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionDto.toString(), responseHeaders, validationEx.getHttpStatus());
}


@ExceptionHandler({ HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException.class, InvalidMimeTypeException.class,
        InvalidMediaTypeException.class, HttpMessageNotReadableException.class })
public ResponseEntity<String> handleMediaTypeNotSupportException(Exception e, HttpServletRequest request,
                                                                 HttpServletResponse response) {

    log.error(EXCEPTION_TRACE, e);

    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

    responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;

    BaseExceptionResponse exceptionDto = new BaseExceptionResponse(httpStatus.value(),
            ExceptionMessages.BAD_REQUEST_DEFAULT);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionDto.toString(), responseHeaders, httpStatus);
}


@ExceptionHandler({ HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class })
public ResponseEntity<String> handleMethodNotSupportException(Exception e, HttpServletRequest request,
                                                              HttpServletResponse response) {

    log.error(EXCEPTION_TRACE, e);

    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

    responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED;

    BaseExceptionResponse exceptionDto = new BaseExceptionResponse(httpStatus.value(),
            ExceptionMessages.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionDto.toString(), responseHeaders, httpStatus);
}

@ExceptionHandler({ MissingServletRequestParameterException.class })
public ResponseEntity<String> handleMissingServletRequestParameterException(Exception e, HttpServletRequest request,
                                                                            HttpServletResponse response) {

    log.error(EXCEPTION_TRACE, e);

    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

    responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;

    BaseExceptionResponse exceptionDto = new BaseExceptionResponse(httpStatus.value(),
            ExceptionMessages.BAD_REQUEST_DEFAULT);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionDto.toString(), responseHeaders, httpStatus);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you answered half of the answer yourself, **Query Params** are used for filtration purposes, and as you can see in your code this will be allowed via GET request. But your question regarding validations is something a trade-off.

For example; if you don't want to have this kind of check, you can depend on mandatory `required = true` which is the default in `@RequestParam`, and handle it in the response immediately.

Or you can use alternatively **@RequestBody** with support of **@Valid** for more clear info for what wrong had occurred; for example

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/order")
public ResponseEntity<?> submitRequest(@RequestBody @Valid OrderRequest requestBody, 
            Errors errors) throws Exception {

        if (errors.hasErrors())
            throw new BusinessException("ERR-0000", "", HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(sendOrder(requestBody), HttpStatus.CREATED);
}

// Your Pojo
public class OrderRequest {
    @NotNull(message = "channel is required")
    private String channel;

    @NotNull(message = "Party ID is required")
    private long partyId;
}
```

For more information check this [@Valid usage in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation)

This way will decouple your validation mechanism from Controller layer to Business layer. which in turns will save lots of boilerplate code, but as you noticed with change to POST instead.

> So in general, there is no direct answer to your question, and the short answer is it depends, so choose whatever easy for you with good capabilities and less maintainance  will be the best practice

Comment: @invisus was explicitly asking about GET requests, not POSTs.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution besides other ones, you can use `JpaSpecificationExecutor<T>` in your repository and create a specification object based on your arguments and pass it to the `findAll` method.

So, your repository should extend from the `JpaSpecificationExecutor<Customer>` interface as follows:

```
@Repository
interface CustomerRepository extends JpaSpecificationExecutor<Customer> {

}
```

Your controller should get the required arguments as `Map<String, String` to gain dynamic behavior.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customers")
public class CustomerController {
    private final CustomerRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public CustomerController(CustomerRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public Page<Customer> findAll(@RequestBody HashMap<String, String> filters, Pageable pageable) {
        return repository.findAll(QueryUtils.toSpecification(filters), pageable);
    }
}
```

And, you should define a method to convert provided arguments to `Specification<Customer>`:

```
class QueryUtils {
    public static Specification<Customer> toSpecification(Map<String, String> filters) {
        Specification<Customer> conditions = null;

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : filters.entrySet()) {
            Specification<Customer> condition = Specification.where((root, query, cb) -> cb.equal(root.get(entry.getKey()), entry.getValue()));
            if (conditions == null) {
                conditions = condition;
            } else {
                conditions = conditions.and(condition);
            }
        }

        return conditions;
    }
}
```

Also, You can use the `Meta` model to make better criteria query and combine it with the provided solution.